# What is the source of this C# MAUI ListView Warning: Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.Diagnostics.BindingDiagnostics: Warning: property not found

Tags: c#, listview, maui

**I'm new to .net MAUI** and I'm trying to understand why I'm getting a warning in this very simple single page project.

**The code below runs fine on both Windows and Android**, in that it correctly displays a list of voters that I have in an SQLite database, **however I am get warnings in my debug log as I populate the ListView and I'd like to fix them.**

The code and the warnings are below.

### MainPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="SOTest.MainPage">

    <ScrollView>
            <VerticalStackLayout>

            <Button 
                    Text="Search"
                    Clicked="OnButtonClicked" />

            <ListView 
                x:Name="MyListView"
                ItemsSource="{Binding DataToDisplay}">

                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <VerticalStackLayout Padding="5">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding first_name}" />
                                    <Label Text="{Binding last_name}" />
                                </VerticalStackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>

                </ListView>

            </VerticalStackLayout>
     </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

### MainPage.xaml. cs

```
using SQLite;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace SOTest;

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{

    //--- Data Model
    public class MyDataModel
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int voter_id { get; set; }
        public string first_name { get; set; }
        public string last_name { get; set; }
        public string street_name { get; set; }
    }



    //--- Database Constants
    public static class DatabaseConstants
    {
        public const string DatabaseFilename = "TestDatabase.db3";

        public const SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags Flags =
            // open the database in read/write mode
            SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite |
            // create the database if it doesn't exist
            SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags.Create |
            // enable multi-threaded database access
            SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags.SharedCache;

        public static string DatabasePath =>
            Path.Combine(FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory, DatabaseFilename);
    }



    //--- Database Operations
    SQLiteAsyncConnection Database;

    public async Task SetUpDb()
    {
        if (Database is not null)
            return;

        Database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(DatabaseConstants.DatabasePath, DatabaseConstants.Flags);
        await Database.CreateTableAsync<MyDataModel>();
    }

    public async Task AddRecord(MyDataModel myRecord)
    {
        await SetUpDb();
        await Database.InsertAsync(myRecord);
        Debug.WriteLine($"Inserted {myRecord.first_name} {myRecord.last_name}");
    }

    public async Task<List<MyDataModel>> GetSomeRecords(string LastNameFilter)
    {
        await SetUpDb();
        return await Database.QueryAsync<MyDataModel>("SELECT * FROM [MyDataModel] WHERE [last_name] = '" + LastNameFilter + "' COLLATE NOCASE");
    }

    public async Task<List<MyDataModel>> GetAllRecords()
    {
        await SetUpDb();
        return await Database.Table<MyDataModel>().ToListAsync();
    }



    //--- Observable Collection
    public ObservableCollection<MyDataModel> DataToDisplay { get; set; }



    //--- Main Page and Event Handlers
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataToDisplay = new ObservableCollection<MyDataModel>() { };
        BindingContext = this;
    }

    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        await SetUpDb();

        MyDataModel Record1 = new MyDataModel();
        Record1.first_name = "Albert";
        Record1.last_name = "Albertson";
        await AddRecord(Record1);

        MyDataModel Record2 = new MyDataModel();
        Record2.first_name = "Betty";
        Record2.last_name = "Boop";
        await AddRecord(Record2);

        MyDataModel Record3 = new MyDataModel();
        Record3.first_name = "Chris";
        Record3.last_name = "Kringle";
        await AddRecord(Record3);

    }

    //--- Button Click Initiates the Query and ListView Population
    private async void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataToDisplay.Clear();
        var MyList = await GetAllRecords();
        if (MyList.Count > 0)
        {
            var i = 0;
            foreach (var item in MyList)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"Adding {item.first_name}");
                DataToDisplay.Add(item);
                i++;
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("No Records");
        }

    }

}
```

### Output

Here's what it looks like after pressing the Search button on Windows:
[image: Project running in Windows]

### Warning Message

Below are the warnings I receive while populating my ListView:

```
Adding Albert
Adding Betty
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.Diagnostics.BindingDiagnostics: Warning: 'first_name' property not found on 'SOTest.MainPage', target property: 'Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Label.Text'
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.Diagnostics.BindingDiagnostics: Warning: 'last_name' property not found on 'SOTest.MainPage', target property: 'Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Label.Text'
Adding Chris
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.Diagnostics.BindingDiagnostics: Warning: 'first_name' property not found on 'SOTest.MainPage', target property: 'Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Label.Text'
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.Diagnostics.BindingDiagnostics: Warning: 'last_name' property not found on 'SOTest.MainPage', target property: 'Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Label.Text'
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.Diagnostics.BindingDiagnostics: Warning: 'first_name' property not found on 'SOTest.MainPage', target property: 'Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Label.Text'
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.Diagnostics.BindingDiagnostics: Warning: 'last_name' property not found on 'SOTest.MainPage', target property: 'Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Label.Text'
```

### What do i need to do to eliminate these warnings?

#### THANK YOU for any suggestions!

Comment: Check you connection string and make sure you are using the same database.  You are using SQLLite and probably the database is a file.  Make sure the file is exactly the same between working and non working apps.  The filename would be in the connection string.

Comment: This was a simplified version of my original and you caught that error - thanks!  I fixed it but still have the same problem as before.

Comment: You may want to post at following : https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8433

Comment: @jdweng - per https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8433 - I eliminated the warnings by using a CollectionView.

Comment: CollectionView is what most people found to work at the link I provided.

Answer (score 1):

add a [DataType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/compiled-bindings) to the `DataTemplate`

```
<DataTemplate x:DataType="myxmlns:MyDataType">
```

Comment: I believe this might be my problem, however, I'm having trouble trying to implement it.  Can you give me more specifics on how to implement it?  Thanks